# Is there any difference in meaning and usage between "with each day" and "day by day"?

Tags: difference

Could you tell me if there is there any difference in meaning and usage between *with each day* and *day by day*? For example:

> It's getting harder at work **with each day**, but I think I'll pull through.
>
> It's getting harder at work **day by day**, but I think I'll pull through.

Comment: Both your versions are syntactically fine, and there's no reason to infer any difference in *meaning*, but idiomatically speaking I'd prefer *It's getting harder at work with each **passing** day...*

Comment: Another good answer, @FumbleFingers -- why not make it so (instead of just a comment)?

Comment: @tkp: I see no scope for recognising a difference in meaning in the *exact* context as given, but I more than suspect there would be differences in other contexts. Also, I don't want to go out on a limb and claim that OP's first version is "unacceptable" without the word ***passing***, but I think I'd struggle to find many examples of that form in Google Books. So coward that I am, I'm waiting to see if anyone else wants to say they don't like it without ***passing***.

Comment: I've seen more than one of your answers, and you appear to know what you're talking about. So go on, head out on that there limb! :-) Besides, there's nothing to stop someone adding their own answer if they disagree with you. This is English after all. In the end, no one really knows why we say *anything*!